# Databricks notebook ipywidgets not working as expected

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on Azure databricks(IDE). I wanted to create a button which takes a text value as input and on the click of a button a function needed to be run which prints the value entered.
For that I created this code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def my_function(param):
    print(f"The parameter is: {param}")

text_input = widgets.Text(description="Enter text:")
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")

display(text_input)
display(button)

def on_button_click(b):
    my_function(text_input.value)

button.on_click(on_button_click)
```

But when I click the button, nothing happens. It should run the `my_function` and print the input text.

Strangely this exact code works fine when I run it in **jupyter notebook**.

I am not able to make it work in **Azure Databricks**.

Any insights would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same code as you, I was unable to generate the function call on button click. However, making the following changes worked.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def my_function(param):
    print(f"The parameter is: {param}")

text_input = widgets.Text(description="Enter text:")
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
output = widgets.Output()

display(text_input)
display(button, output)

def on_button_click(b):
    with output:
        print("button is clicked")
        my_function(text_input.value)

button.on_click(on_button_click)
```

[image]